# Determining the indicies where 2 numpy arrays differ

Tags: python, numpy, array-difference

I've got 2 long numpy arrays, both having 508 elements. I would like to get the indices of where they differ. Most of the solutions I've seen determining difference here sort the arrays which is not suitable in my case.

Example

`arr_1 = [0, 1, 4, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 5, ... , 5, 5, 6]`

`arr_1 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, ... , 5, 0, 6]`

Hopefully returning something like:

`solut = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ... , 0, 1, 0]`

or even

`solut = [2, 4, 8, ..., n-2]`

Is there an efficient way to do this in numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would harness `numpy.equal` following way

```
import numpy as np 
arr_1 = [0, 1, 4, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6]
arr_2 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 6]
solut = (~np.equal(arr_1, arr_2)).astype(int)
print(solut)
```

output

```
[0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0]
```

Explanation: use `numpy.equal` to get array of `False`s and `True`s where `arr_1`-`arr_2` pairs are equal, then negating (using `~`) finally converting booleans to `int`. If you are interested in indices of nonzero use `numpy.flatnonzero` function:

```
indices = np.flatnonzero(solut)
print(indices)
```

output

```
[ 2  4  8 10]
```

In this case you do not need to convert array to `int`s before feeding into `numpy.flatnonzero`.

Comment: There is also ```np.flatnonzero``` that works for 1d arrays, which ```solut``` is.

Answer (score 2):

You can just write `arr = arr_1 == arr_2`. This code gives you a boolean array with true if they are equal and false if not. Then you can use `np.where` to find the indices where the arrays are equal or not.